# Get XmlSerializer to ignore property on base base class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a class (`MyBasicHttpBinding`) that inherits from `BasicHttpBinding` which in turn implements `HttpBindingBase`.

`HttpBindingBase` has a property ProxyAddress.

I want to serialize `MyBasicHttpBinding` but I want to ignore `HttpBindingBase.ProxyAddress`.

I have a method on `MyBasicHttpBinding` called `ToXml()` The implementation of which looks like so:

```
public string ToXml()
{
    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    overrides.Add(this.GetType(), "ProxyAddress", new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true });

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType(), overrides);
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var writer = new StringWriter(builder);

    serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

I have tried `System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding` in the add overrides bit and that didnt work either.

I have also tried adding:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool ProxyAddressSpecified = false;
```

To `MyBasicHttpBinding` and a `ShouldSerializeProxyAddress()` method.

None of these have stopped `XmlSerializer` trying to serialize `HttpBindingBase.ProxyAddress`.

So basically I don't want `HttpBindingBase.ProxyAddress` to serialize, but cant work out how.

Comment: Why do you not want to serialize it? It is actually a part of your class. If you serialize the base, it will be there. So it should be there in the derived type.

Comment: Main reason being that its of type Uri which does not serialize, and as I don't need the information from the property after serialization I thought the simplest solution would be to ignore that property.

Comment: Well when you want that custom serialization behaviour (which isn't actually then serializing the object as is) you can implement `IXmlSerializable` to serialize only the information you need.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I thought one of the above methods might have done the job too, but I am obviously missing some understanding. If you know why they don't work as I expected and wouldn't mind explaining why I would appreciate it.